# prepend digit to filenames which begin with digits (with zmv, please)

Tags: zsh, regular-expression, rename

I have a directory with files named like `19.png`, `20.jpeg`, and `README00.txt`

I want to rename these to `119.png`, `120.jpeg`, and `README00.txt`.

I would like to do this with zmv as it works well in so many other cases, but I cannot get zmv to make an action based on the first character of a filename being a digit. I can easily get `1README00.txt`, but that is not what I desire.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash

Answer (score 4):

```
zmv '([0-9]*)' '1$1'
```

This adds a `1` in front of a filename which starts with a digit.